# How do water based solutions (cream, gels) etc permeable through hydrophobic skin?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, lipids

Most skin care products or the sort are oily, lipid based.
Our skin is hydrophobic. I reckon the reason is to be easily permeable through the skin.

So how do these skin care or any products which are water based said to have higher absorption and provide high nutrient uptake, replenish skin?

How I see it, that it's like a slight burst in the cell since a hypertonic solution seep into the hypotonic cell(!?). And still confused how such product could replenish skin.

I am keen on the chemistry behind this concept of how a water based skin care could actually replenish the skin. In the discussion, it is better not to include, point at any specific products you loathe or adore them.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon.  I got rid of your comments because we try to avoid medical advice on the site.

Comment: Don't worry. I certainly understand. The only reason I even commented was to let your members know that deeper penetration by topical cosmetic ingredients is not necessarily a good thing.  Consumer manufactures try to avoid it, frankly.